# IBM-MQ Docker with repository ibm-messaging/mq-container

Tags: docker, ibm-mq

I have an error when i run this command :

```
MQ_ARCHIVE=IBM_MQ_9.0.0.0_LINUX_X86-64_TRIAL.tar.gz MQ_VERSION=9.0.0.0 make build-advancedserver
```

The output is :

```
Step 1/7 : ARG BASE_IMAGE=mq-sdk:9.0.5.0-x86_64-ubuntu-16.04
Step 2/7 : FROM $BASE_IMAGE
pull access denied for mq-sdk, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
make: *** [build-golang-sdk] Error 1
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Providing comment on behalf of @LaurenceBonney "Which branch of the mq git repo are you using? Could you reply with the git clone command you used prior to running this command."

Comment: If you are not aware you just click the "add a comment" link to add a comment in reply to someones question.